# Failed to open a session for the virtual machine (0x80004005). I wrote wrong one of the codes in CMD and now I get this error message in VirtualBox

Tags: cmd, virtual-machine, virtualbox, command-prompt

**The codes that I have put in CMD are:**

```
cd "C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\"

VBoxManage.exe modifyvm "Mac" --cpuidset 00000001 000106e5 00100800 0098e3fd bfebfbff

VBoxManage setextradata "Mac" "VBoxInternal/Devices/efi/0/Config/DmiSystemProduct" "iMac11,3"

VBoxManage setextradata "Mac" "VBoxInternal/Devices/efi/0/Config/DmiSystemVersion" "1.0"

VBoxManage setextradata "Mac" "VBoxInternal/Devices/efi/0/Config/DmioardProduct" "Iloveapple"

VBoxManage setextradata "Mac" "VBoxInternal/Devices/smc/0/Config/DeviceKey" "ourhardworkbythesewordsguardedpleasedontsteal(c)AppleComputerInc"

VBoxManage setextradata "Mac" "VBoxInternal/Devices/smc/0/Config/GetKeyFromRealSMC" 1
```

Instead of writing "DmiBoardProduct" I have written "DmioardProduct"... and now when I try to run the Virtual Machine I get this message:

```
Unknown configuration value '/DmioardProduct' found in the configuration of efi instance #0 (VERR_CFGM_CONFIG_UNKNOWN_VALUE).
```

Please help me, how can I correct it? I need your instructions! I'm not an expert.

Answer (score 1):

You can run the following command to delete the extra setting, or edit the virtual machine configuration file manually.

```
VBoxManage setextradata "Mac" "VBoxInternal/Devices/efi/0/Config/DmioardProduct"
```